# Softkeyboard covers buttons and text behind it while appearing onto the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i know this question has been discussed before but i have almost tried every possible solution but nothing seems to work. 
i want my buttons and text to move up when the softkeyboard appears. now the softkeyboard hides the text and button behind it.
also i have added scrollview and changed my app manifest file, still it does not move the buttons up neither does it scrolls.

Any help is appreciated
thank you

my xml code is

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CleaningBudgetAndMenPowerFeb13">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/Cleaning_Budget_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/attachpic" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/TotalBudgetSelection"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Cleaning_Budget_toolbar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/et_bg_services"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Total"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/hourlyRateSelection"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/TotalBudgetSelection"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/et_bg_services"
        android:backgroundTint="#cfcaca"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Hourly rate"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/hourlyRateSelection"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:padding="10dp">


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/whatIsYourBudget"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="What is your budget" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/InputAmountForTotalLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/whatIsYourBudget"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/et_bg_services"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="د.ب" />


        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
     >


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/HoursInHourlyRate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Hours" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/HoursinputInHourlyrateLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/HoursInHourlyRate"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/et_bg_services"
                android:padding="10dp" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/PayInHourlyRate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/HoursinputInHourlyrateLayout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Pay"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/PayInHours"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/PayInHourlyRate"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/et_bg_services"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="د.ب" />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/howManyPeoplDoYouNeed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="How many people do you need?" />



    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/increaseWorkerbutton"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/howManyPeoplDoYouNeed"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/budget_increase"
        android:text="+"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/decreaseWorkerbutton"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/decreaseWorkerbutton"
        android:layout_below="@id/howManyPeoplDoYouNeed"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/budget_decrease"
        android:text="-"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/increaseWorkerbutton" />




    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/howManyPeoplDoYouNeed"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/increaseWorkerbutton"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/decreaseWorkerbutton"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/budgettext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="@string/Budget_resource"
            android:textColor="#6dbe3a"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/budgettext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/TotalAmountToPayperPerson"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2.000 BD"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/PerPersonAmount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Per Person"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/TotalAmountIfHourlyRate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Total :"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="16sp" />



            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/TotalAmountInEnd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="16.000 BD"
              />

        </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/ContinueToImages"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_services"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:text="Continue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    </RelativeLayout>





</RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Below is the App Manifest regarding the intended activity

```
    <activity android:name=".CleaningBudgetAndMenPowerFeb13"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        />
```

Style.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>

</style>

<style name="Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>

<style name="FilterDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following attribute to your activity tag inside the manifest.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

adjustPan slides up the entire screen to keep it in view. You can also use adjustResize if you want it to just resize the screen for the available space.

Note* if you are using fullscreen activity without toolbar the adjustResize attribute does not work properly.

Comment: Share a screenshot and your manifest declaration of the activity. Also if your activity has a theme attached like AppTheme via the application or via it's own tag, share the theme so I can inspect those as well

Comment: Also worth noting, just a friendly comment, no offense intended here. But your UI visual tree is far too deep, too many nested layouts wrapping layouts, wrapping layouts. You should focus on making that more shallow, cleaning it up, using appropriate layout parents to handle your needs. You can accomplish the same layout with far less xml elements which will cleanup your troubleshooting of UI handling as well as load faster. I count 8 parent layouts used for one screen here. Relative and Linear

Comment: i have added the app manifest file in the question above..ill try to reduce the xml tags and make them more appropriate..thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Ok so it's inheriting the AppTheme. Can you supply the AppTheme from styles.xml

Comment: Hi, It started working by following the way u initially showed but i removed         getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
 from on create which was creating the trouble

Comment: Ahh ok, yeah I didn't have access to your code or I would of caught that with ya. Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Any time, glad to help